# Using the same variable but with different results

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
var b = 10 - a
var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * b )
var d = a + c


console.log("Jupiter threw " + a + " for the first round!")
console.log("Jupiter threw " + c + " for the second round!")
console.log("Jupiter scored a total of " + d + " points!")

console.log("Jupiter threw " + a + " for the first round!")
console.log("Jupiter threw " + c + " for the second round!")
console.log("Jupiter scored a total of " + d + " points!")
```

I'm a beginner to javascript trying to make a game and was wondering if you could use the same variable multiple times or do I have to make a new variable for each round?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to make but ye you can reuse variables for example you can make a button new game and create an onclick function which for example does: 'a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)' so every time you click the button your variable 'a' will run the code and have a different value.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not very clear what exactly you are asking for. You can reuse the variables as long as you dont mind the values being overwritten. How exactly are you running multiple 'rounds'?  Ideally, you put that code in a function and call it for each round. Please consider reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and updating your question in the interest of clarity

Comment: Yes variables can be used multiple times, hence the name *variable*.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the dynamic data types, so basically you can assign `String` or `number` or `boolean` to the same variable it doesn't matter.

It actually depends on your architecture how you have architect your game. You have to spend some time on this but if your architect can handle a variable go ahead no problem. Else you can use multiple variables also.

Comment: I dont think this answers the question, the question is can you use variables multiple times

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. Since OP is making some kind of game so you can not guarantee that OP can use the same variables multiple times or not, because you don't know the behavior of game.

Comment: -1 reusing the variable for different types is ill-advised and just bad advice, if you take time to architect your code, you should use meaningful variable names and not try to use something cryptic/obscure, which using variables for different types will lead to.

Comment: @BotNet I don't think there is something wrong with using the same variable for different types if the architect can bear that. Rather than creating different variables if OP can reuse that variable I don't think there is anything wrong with that. Any way JavaScript itself allow this one. Reusing the variable just saves the memory.

Comment: *Saving memory* is a micro-optimization to the Nth degree.  Yes there is something wrong if variables are being reused.  To be clear, this isn't reusing the name, this is reusing the actual variable.  `let foo = 'bar';  loginWith(foo);  foo = 3;  setPersonAgeTo(foo); emailAfter(foo);`  There is a disassociation of what *foo* represents throughout the code and that is a maintenance nightmare.  Just because the language allows for something, doesn't mean it should be conducted.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the same variables you just don't declare them with var after they are first initialized. See the example below.

```js
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
var b = 10 - a
var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * b )
var d = a + c


console.log("Jupiter threw " + a + " for the first round!")
console.log("Jupiter threw " + c + " for the second round!")
console.log("Jupiter scored a total of " + d + " points!")

 a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
 b = 20 - a
 c = Math.floor(Math.random() * b )
 d = a + c

console.log("Jupiter threw " + a + " for the first round!")
console.log("Jupiter threw " + c + " for the second round!")
console.log("Jupiter scored a total of " + d + " points!")
```